# Prove that if $f\in L^p(R^n)$ then two functions exist $f_1 \in L^{p1}(R^n)$ and $f_1 \in L^{p2}(R^n)$ so that $f=f_1+f_2$, $1\le p1< p< p2\le+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^p({R^n})$. I consider the set $E=\{x\in R^n: |f(x)|>1\}$ and I defined $f_1=f \chi_{E}$ and $f_2=f \chi_{E^c}$. So $f=f_1+f_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof when  $1 <p_1<p<p_2 <\infty$: $\int |f_1|^{p_1} \leq (\int |f|^{p})^{p_1/p} (\mu (E))^{1/q}$ where $\frac {p_1} p +\frac   1 q=1$. Hence $f_1 \in L^{p_1}$. [Note that $\mu(E) <\infty$ because $f \in L^{p}$]. Now $\int|f_2|^{p_2} \leq \int |f|^{p} <\infty$ so $f_2 \in L^{p_2}$. I will let you handle the other cases.

Comment: which are the other cases?

Comment: I have taken strict inequality for the parameters. The other case are when  there are some equalities. For example, $p=p_1$ is one of them.  @GiuliaB.

Answer (score 1):

I have correct the text of the exercise.

My solution:

Let $f\in L^p(R^n)$ and $E=\{x \in R^n: |f(x)|>1\}$

I define $f_1=f \chi_E$ and $f_2=f \chi_{E^c}$ so $f=f_1+f_2$

Because $f\in L^p(R^n)$ then $f_1,f_2\in L^p(R^n)$

$\int_{R^n} |f_1|^{p1} d\mu=\int_{R^n} |f|^{p1} \chi _E(x) dx\le\int_{R^n} |f|^{p} \chi _E(x) dx< +\infty$

so $||f_1||_{p1}<+\infty$ and $f_1 \in L^{p1}(R^n)$

$\int_{R^n} |f_2|^{p2} d\mu=\int_{R^n} |f|^{p2} \chi _{E^c}(x) dx\le\int_{R^n} |f|^{p} \chi _{E^c}(x) dx< +\infty$

so $||f_2||_{p2}<+\infty$ and $f_2 \in L^{p1}(R^n)$

Have I to study other cases?